# Static patching of ELF64 binary on Linux

Tags: linux, static, binary, instrumentation

I have a static executable ELF64 binary. There are certain functions that I want to override and change the handling. It will result in new functions getting added. Now I need to patch this executable with the new handling.

I understand that this ain't a new problem but I couldn't find anything conclusive that works:

1. LD_PRELOAD ain't useful because I am working with static binaries.
2. eresi/elfsh doesn't work for X86-64 ELF binaries
3. pwntools and other elf tools lack the feature of patching and extending segments.
4. Don't require runtime instrumentation provided by Pin, Valgrind, and similar other tools. Runtime instrumentation impacts runtime performance. My executable will be spawned into thousand processes on the same machine. (Performance hit to the tune of ~5% is still ok)

https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-asia-02/Clowes/bh-asia-02-clowes.pdf

Explains the problem statement and the technical aspects without specifying the tools used in the context.

What are my other options?

Answer (score 0):

Hot patching would be easier to do and would give you [a greater range of choice](https://github.com/kubo/funchook/wiki/List-of-API-Hook-Libraries) in implementation, but it sounds like you've already considered this and decided you prefer patching the binary by replacing the symbols instead.

Static binary patchers are easier to develop but they put more burden on the user. Consider [elfpatch](https://github.com/dpocock/elfpatch). In order to use this tool to patch an executable called `myelf` to replace a function called `myfunc()` with your own function that returns 0 you would do:

`elfpatch.py --apply --symbol-file symbols.txt myelf`

Here the contents of symbols.txt would be:

`myfunc b800000000c3`

Where `b800000000c3` is x86 machine code for `return 0;`. This is simple enough as long as the patched function is simple, but the more complicated the function gets, the more complicated the process is going to get, especially if you have to preserve and call the original function, and if that function calls other functions in other libraries...

Comment: Thanks mnistic for the sample usage of elfpatch.py. But my use-case is more complicated. I got to replace the entire function (and possibly add new functions) to existing elf.

Comment: This tool _will_ replace the entire function. As far as adding new functions, I don't know what use-case could possibly call for that, but if you really need it you may have to extend the tool, or find something else. `objcopy` is the industry standard, but AFAIK it will also require significant work on your part.